# Problem with result of query in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgis-1.5

I run the following query and irrelevant of the point coordinates and radius I always recieve all the records of the table I'm querying. Can anyone point out what the problem could be with this query?

```
SELECT * FROM Buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 26918), 2000, 'quad_segs=8'),0);
```

Just to be clear, my aim is to select all buildings that fall into a selected circular buffer.  Here the (0,0) are the coordinates of the center of circle and 2000 is the radius. No matter what value I put for these, the query returns all the records of table.

Please help!

The following image shows the results of 12 records:
[image]

Comment: Can you show some representative data (e.g. ```SELECT AsEWKT(geom) FROM Buildings LIMIT 5```)

Comment: @BradHards I've updated the question with an image of the output. Any clue what the problem could be?

Comment: by the way, I tried AsEWKT(geom), it seems the function is unknown to PostGIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select all buildings that fall into a selected circular buffer with a 2000 radius you need this command:

```
SELECT * FROM Buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 26918)), 2000);
```

See [this](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/dataadmin/pgBasics/spatialrelationships.html), for more examples.

---

**EDIT1:**

I've gave you already the right answer!

To prove you I'll show the tests I've done before answering to you, on **my test data** (my SRID is 31700):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to see the selected points in QGIS then you need to follow the images bellow:

[image]

[image]

So, I think that your center point coordinates **are not [0, 0]** and if you'll follow carefully my demonstration you'll obtain the proper results!

---

**EDIT2:**

My tests showed me that it is possible a user to keep its data in a PostGIS table with the 4326 SRID, and to obtain a proper result, like above, using its own SRID (e.g. 26918).

[image]

In this case one my use this command:

```
SELECT * FROM Buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(geom, 26918), (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 26918)), 2000);
```

Yet, in this case, I've noticed that the selected points are still in the 4326 SRID. Therefore, if you create a table based on this query, eventually, you need to update the table SRID to your own.

Here's what I've done (**using my test data**) prior to see the selected point in QGIS:

[image]

But, the newly created table has the 4326 SRID:

[image]

Therefore, we need to change it to our own:

[image]

(I've verified my solution, considering the buildings are **points, polygons and multipolygons**, and didn't noticed any other problems than those already presented here.)

[image]

Comment: The problem still remains. Gives back all the records. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorin: the data is not in SRID 26918. Check the binary blobs in the updated screenshot.

Comment: ST_DWithin cannot mix SRID. So your solution works if the_geom is in 31700, but not if its in 4326.

Comment: @SorinCălinică, Thank you for step by step instruction. I understand all, I tried the same, but still have all records of my table as return! :( I am sure I pass a valid point for the center of circle. Do you have any other suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: @Sorina, Thank you for the update. I am still confused. I get my point (center of circle) from the user click in Openlayers map. I click on Germany for example and it gives me this point: POINT(1116858.6062789 7088526.4511342), do you know in which SRID is this point? I guess I have to know this in order to transform it using ST_Transform function....

Comment: I found out, it was in 900913! Anyway, now the problem is solved. Although, BradHards gave the same correct answer as you did, but I will tick yours, since it has more information step by step, and can help others whom might have the same problem in the future. Thank you: :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a total shot in the dark.  Check the coordinate system for your building table, if it's not in UTM 18N it could be causing the query to return everything.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output you've shown (which would have been a lot easier to read if you'd converted it to EWKT first), your data is referenced to EPSG 4326 (that is what the E610 part of the geometry blob is - 4326 in hexadecimal). EPSG 4326 is WGS-84 long/lat.

The [documentation for ST_DWithin](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html) says:

> For Geometries: The distance is specified in units defined by the
>   spatial reference system of the geometries. For this function to make
>   sense, the source geometries must both be of the same coordinate
>   projection, having the same SRID.

SRID 4326 is not the same as the SRID you are trying to use - 26918.

So you need to transform everything in to a common SRID. dblanchett had it right!

The transform function is [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html). There are a couple of options here - you can transform the whole table to 26918 (creating a new table), or you can do the transform as part of the query.

Here is an example of the latter:

```
SELECT * FROM Buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(geom, 26918), ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 26918), 2000, 'quad_segs=8'),0)
```

(Obviously you'll need to fix the centre point to something that is reasonable for your data).

Hint: ST_MakePoint is usually better than calling ST_GeomFromText on a static string point set.

Comment: Right, the table SRID is 4326, and therefor I changed the value SRID in query to 4326. Still have the same problem. the new query is like below: (any idea where I'm doing wrong?)

Comment: SELECT * FROM Buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326), 2000, 'quad_segs=8'),0);

Comment: Read the documentation again. "The distance is specified in units defined by the spatial reference system of the geometries." 4326 is in degrees. So you just asked for 2000 degrees, which isn't what you want. Do it in UTM, as I showed.

Comment: If I give a wrong center point which does not fall into the dataset, shouldn't it give me a 0(zero) result as query instead of all data in table?

Comment: Don't rush. Just read the documentation.

Comment: I read the documention, and also used your query. This time the result of query is 0(zero), but I am sure I use a valid point as center of circle, and there should be lots of objects returned within that buffer. Do you have any other suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: I also tried using ST_MakePoint, but again gave me no results as output, see query below:

Comment: SELECT * FROM Buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(geom, 26918), ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(9.85944169997464 , 53.5852898999091), 26918), 2000, 'quad_segs=8'),0)

Comment: That point is not really in 26918. Perhaps you wanted to use UTM easting/northing, not degrees. Alternatively you could use ST_Transform 4326 to 26918.

Comment: I get this point from the database when I use ST_Astext(). And if I use the data from OpenLayers (users clicks on map) I get something like:
POINT(1116858.6062789 7088526.4511342). Do you know which SRID is this later POINT in?

Comment: You were right, now the problem is fixed. both you and Sorin gave the correct answer, but I checked Sorin's as the correct answer, just because it has more information in a step by step manner, and can help others whom might have the same problem in the future. Thank you for the time you put (+1)